# Split string input into jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

```
string[] listKeys = key.Split(',');
string[] OrKeys;
string[][] AdvListKeys;
for (int i = 0; i < listKeys.Length; i++)
{
    OrKeys = listKeys[i].Split('|');
    for (int j = 0; j < OrKeys.Length; j++)
    {
        AdvListKeys = new string[i][j];
        AdvListKeys[i][j] = OrKeys[i];
    }
}
```

I am trying to enter string `"glu|com,inf|ina"` into jagged array in `C#` in such way that it's columns would be defined by the length of `listKeys` (split by comas) and rows defined by the length of `OrKeys` (split by the '|') and the values stored in the jagged array would be `{"glu", "com"}` for column 1 and `{"inf", "ina"}` for column 2! 
Currently I am getting this error:

> Error  2   Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']'
>   Can someone help?

Comment: I did not understand. You want to associate a key for each string? If you must use a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot instantiate both dimensions of a jagged array at the same time.  That's because each array in the array can have a different length.

But it's much easier to do this with Linq

```
string[][] AdvListKeys = key.Split(',')
                            .Select(o => o.Split('|'))
                            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make the following changes:

Instantiate your 2d array outside of your loops

```
AdvListKeys = new string[listKeys.Length][];
```

Since `AdvListKeys` is basically an array of arrays, you can set it's values by assigning the value in `OrKeys` to the elements of `AdvListKeys`

```
AdvListKeys[i] = OrKeys;
```

you don't need that second loop to do this(the one that iterates over `j`)